# How to generate a random number in Elixir?

Tags: random, integer, elixir

I need to generate a random number. I found the [`Enum.random/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) function, but it expects an enumerable such as a list or range of numbers.

Is that the only way to get a random number?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can call [Erlang's `rand` module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html) from Elixir code seamlessly.

```
random_number = :rand.uniform(n)
```

Will give a random number from 1 <= x <= n

Comment: And don't (accidentally) use the old and now-deprecated Erlang `random` module.

Answer (score 85):

`&Enum.random/1`

`Enum.random(0..n)` will generate `0 to n` randomly

you can send list as argument too

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this was probably downvoted because the question was asking for a different way than what you suggested.

Comment: Note that the documentation for `Enum.random/1` when passed a range will *not* traverse the entire range, so the execution time of `Enum.random(1..1000000000000)` and `Enum.random(1..1000)` is the same.

Answer (score 10):

As perhaps [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42295898/173497) implies, you *can* use [`Enum.random/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) but you *don't* in fact need to pass it "a list of numbers" (as the question, [as originally written](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38778054/1)) assumed.

[As a commenter on that other answer pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778054/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-elixir#comment100081514_42295898), [the docs for `Enum.random/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#random/1) state:

> If a range is passed into the function, this function will pick a random value between the range limits, without traversing the whole range (thus executing in constant time and constant memory).

Thus these should be (at least roughly) equivalent:

```
:rand.uniform(n)
```

```
1..n |> Enum.random()
```

Depending on why exactly you want a 'random' number, you might be able to use [`System.unique_integer/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#unique_integer/1) as well. The following "returns an integer that is unique in the current runtime instance":

```
System.unique_integer()
```

A unique positive integer (which could be useful for generating 'random names'):

```
System.unique_integer([:positive])
```

Unique monotonically increasing integers:

```
System.unique_integer([:monotonic])
```